# Identifying Rows Where Conditions Occur

Tags: partitioning, netezza

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table:

```
  name year var1 var2
  John 2001    a    b
  John 2002    a    a
  John 2003    a    b
  Mary 2001    b    a
  Mary 2002    a    b
  Mary 2003    b    a
 Alice 2001    a    b
 Alice 2002    b    a
 Alice 2003    a    b
   Bob 2001    b    a
   Bob 2002    b    b
   Bob 2003    b    a
```

I want to answer the following question:

- For each name, when (i.e., which row_num) does var1 change for the first time? Keep the full information for that row so we can see the change in var1_before/var1_after and var2_before/var2_after
- If a name kept its var1 value throughout - return the full information row for the last available year corresponding to that name (along with the row_number)

I wrote this code to look at how var1 and var2 change year-to-year for each person:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        name, 
        year, 
        var1, 
        var2,
        LAG(var1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year ASC) AS var1_before,
        LEAD(var1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year ASC) AS var1_after,
        LAG(var2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year ASC) AS var2_before,
        LEAD(var2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year ASC) AS var2_after,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year ASC) AS row_num
    FROM 
        mytable
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
    CTE;
```

But I don't know how to proceed from here. I tried to identify names with changes vs. names with no changes, but I keep getting confused and messing up.

Can someone please show me how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a Netezza instance, but I can give you a hint. Your problem is often referred to as an "island and gap" problem. A simplified setup:

```
create table t
( name varchar(20) not null
, yr integer not null
, var1 char(1) not null
);  

insert into t (name, yr, var1) 
values ('John',2001,'a')
     , ('John',2002,'a')
     , ('John',2003,'b')
     , ('John',2004,'b')
     , ('John',2005,'c')
     , ('Mary',2001,'a')
     , ('Mary',2002,'b')
     , ('Mary',2003,'c')
;
```

If we create one ordering for each name, and one ordering for each name, var1, we can detect where var1 changes via the difference:

```
select name, yr, var1
    , row_number() over (partition by name order by yr)
      - row_number() over (partition by name, var1 order by yr) as grp
from t;

name    yr  var1    grp
John    2001    a   0
John    2002    a   0
John    2003    b   2
John    2004    b   2
John    2005    c   4
Mary    2001    a   0
Mary    2002    b   1
Mary    2003    c   2
```

Since the (partition by name, var1) will restart whenever var1 changes, it will create a "gap" in the grp sequence.

We can then exclude the first grp and get the first row for each name:

```
with tmp1 as (
   select name, yr, var1
       , row_number() over (partition by name order by yr)
          - row_number() over (partition by name, var1 order by yr) as grp
   from t
), tmp2 as (
   select tmp1.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by yr) as rn 
   from tmp1 
   where grp > 0
)
select name, yr, var1 from tmp2 where rn = 1  
;

name    yr  var1
John    2003    b
Mary    2002    b
```

Note that names that do not change var1 will not be part of the result

[Fiddle for postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/SbbDG7Hi)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! can you show me how I can add more columns to the final result? e.g. final_years (the number of years it took for var1 to change for the first time OR the total number of years if var1 did not change), var1_before_ var1_after, var2_before, var2_after ? for names where var1 does not change, I can just keep any row

Comment: The number of years it took for var1 to change for the first time is easy, include grp in the final select: `select name, yr, var1, grp as num_years ...`. Since we removed grp's that did not change, you will have to add them back.